# Text does not fit in cells on other computer

Tags: vba, excel

I have created an Excel file using VBA. The Excel file looks fine on my computer. But when I send it to a colleague, it looks like in the picture. We are both using Excel 2010.

How can I fix this on my computer using VBA before I send it to my colleague or make it so that this doesn't happen in the first place?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a height / line height / cell padding issue (whatever the Excel equivalents of those are). Can Excel do negative margins? Probably impossible to tell without seeing some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I center aligned the text vertically. That solved the problem. I think that PaulGs comment about saving in an older file format could also be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA try to use AutoFit with the data range.
Or you user can select all the cells on the sheet and do a manual autofit by double clicking the outside line on the cell or row header cells.

Something like: Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit

Comment: The user did that. But I am looking for a solution that I can run on my computer before I send it to the colleagues. I will try @pnuts suggesstion to check font availability

Comment: If that doesn't work its possible it could be a compatibility issue and Excel has adjusted your worksheet to compensate. If thats the case, save the sheet with an earlier version.